# Implementing a collection of base classes - should I be needing this much downcasting in derived classes?

Tags: c#, casting

I am implementing a collection of classes that exhibit the following pattern:

```
 public class Animal {}

 public abstract class AnimalToy
 {
      public AnimalToy(Animal owner)
      {
           Owner = owner;
      }

      public Animal Owner { get; private set; }

      /* Various methods related to all toys that use the Owner property */
 }

 public class Dog: Animal 
 {
      public void Bark() {}
 }

 public class PlasticBone: AnimalToy
 {
      public PlasticBone(Dog owner) : base(owner) {}

      public void Throw()
      {
           ((Dog)Owner).Bark();
      }
 }
```

- I have a base class `AnimalToy` with a property that is a reference to another base class `Animal`.
- I now want to implement a `Dog` and a `PlasticBone` toy for that `Dog` class.  `PlasticBone` is a toy that's only valid for dogs, and in fact the constructor restricts the owner of `PlasticBone` to be of type `Dog`.
- `PlasticBone` has a method `Throw()` that is unique to that class, that uses a method on `Dog` (`Bark()`) that is unique to the `Dog` class.  Therefore I need to cast the generic property `Owner` to `Dog` before I can access it.

This works just fine, but in the project I am working on this situation comes up again and again and leads to quite ugly code where the methods of derived classes are full of downcasts of base class references.  Is this normal?  Or is there a better overall design that would be cleaner?

Comment: The key to your problem is where you say *"is a toy that is only valid for dogs"*.  Nominal subtyping is designed around the slightly contradictory ideas that (1) a derived type is *more specific* than a base type, but at the same time (2) you can use an instance of the derived type in *any context* where an instance of the base type is needed. That means that derived types that are *more specific because they have a restriction on their behaviour* automatically violate the second rule.

Comment: Thanks @Eric.  I have to admit the overall design is guilty of that, but my design skills are not yet up to the task of finding a formulation of the problem that avoids that rule violation.  Can you suggest a way that it could be designed differently?

Comment: Your problem is well-known; try doing a web search for "parallel class hierarchy problem". Unfortunately this problem is well-known because there is no obviously best solution to it; it's not your design skills, it's the language itself that makes this tricky. There's a good overview of the problem here: http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try to elaborate a little on the discussion in the comments and hopefully provide you with a generalised, polymorphic solution. The general idea is functionally equivalent to what Carra was suggesting but, hopefully, this will help you to apply those concepts to the domain of your actual problem.

To work with your abstraction of your problem; suppose you have your abstract base class defined like so:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void Catch();
}
```

This is a shift in the semantics of the abstract method; you no longer have an abstract `Bark` method, you simply have a `Catch` method, the semantics of which define it as, essentially "react to something being thrown." How the `Animal` reacts is entirely up to the animal.

So, you'd then define `Dog` like so:

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override void Catch()
    {
        Bark();
    }

    public void Bark()
    {
        // Bark!
    }
}
```

And change your `Throw` method to:

```
public void Throw()
{
    Owner.Catch();
}
```

Now, `Bark` is specific to `Dog`, while the generic `Catch` method is universal to all `Animal`s. The `Animal` class now specifies that its subclasses must implement a method that reacts to items being thrown to it. The fact that the `Dog` barks is entirely up to the `Dog`.

This is the essence of polymorphism - it's not up to the toy to determine what the dog does; it's up to the dog. All the toy needs to know is that the dog can catch it.

More generally, though, I don't like to have two classes that extend independent base classes be logically coupled (parallel hierarchies, as Eric points out) unless one of them explicitly instantiates the other, though it's impossible to offer any real advice on that without seeing your actual solution architecture.

Comment: Thanks @Ant P.  In most situations this would be the best answer to my question, although in my specific case I will probably not be able to avoid parallel hierarchies.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can make `AnimalToy` class generic, by this you can avoid casting.

```
public abstract class AnimalToy<TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal
{
    public AnimalToy(TAnimal owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
    }

    public TAnimal Owner { get; private set; }    
}

public class PlasticBone: AnimalToy<Dog>
{
    public PlasticBone(Dog owner) : base(owner) {}

    public void Throw()
    {
        Owner.Bark();
    }
}
```

Worth noting that `((Dog)Owner)` is not upcast, it is called downcast. upcast is over way around.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sriram.  Sometimes classes have references to classes of the same type... to extend the above example, if `Animal` had a `Parent` property of type `Animal`, and then there was an activity that dogs only did with their parents (e.g. `Bark()` called a `Parent.ResponseBark()`).  To model that with generics, the `Animal` class would have to be generic as well (i.e. `public class Animal<TAnimal> where TAnimal: Animal`) and you would then be declaring new dogs as `Dog Fido = new Dog<Dog>()`.  Somehow this doesn't seem logical to me.  Am I missing a better way to do this?

Comment: @user3676281 I never asked to change animal to generic, and I won't. It is actually another question. I suggest you to ask another question for that with more details. [Polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23870748/2530848) is likely to help you if you don't have anything specific to specific animal.

Comment: Thanks @Sriram for pointing out that this is downcasting not upcasting, I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to fix it:

```
public abstract class Animal 
{
    public abstract void MakeNoise();
}
```

Let dog implement the MakeNoise and you can just call that in your Toy class:

```
public void Throw()
{
    Owner.MakeNoise();
}
```

Comment: +1 - this is basically what I was going to post. If `MakeNoise` isn't semantically correct, then do `Owner.Catch` and call `Bark` inside `Dog.Catch`. This is a case for proper polymorphism, not a good use of generics as in Sriram's answer.

Comment: My choice of method names may have been a little misleading.  I'm agreed that in this specific example, finding a more generic form of Bark() would be the correct approach (thanks Carra).  However, in my real project I have plenty of methods that are not generic.  So is there any way to improve this if Bark() is not a type of activity that all animals do?

Comment: @user - note that in Ant's proposal you don't have `Bark` (or `MakeNoise`) in `Animal`, you have `Catch` in it. That is a shift in the generalization. Although this targets your heavily simplified example, it is an approach that you can indeed (try to) apply to your situtaion. It means you reflect your model and try to find out what exactly (semantically) you really want to generalize. I.e. if bark is general, pull it up. If throw is general, pull it up. If throw and bark are both special to dog, then there is no need to generalize.

Comment: @AntP - your difference seems small at a first glance but is actually a different approach which IMHO qualifies it as a separate answer.